# Problema con git, push marcado con otra cuenta

Tags: git, git-push

Hola y gracias de antemano, entré en una empresa y al no tener la cuenta de git configurada me prestó otra persona la suya para ir viendo el proyecto.

Posteriormente me dieron mi cuenta de la empresa y empecé a trabajar sin ningún problema, pero hoy ya me han cambiado de proyecto y al hacer push desde visual studio en git sale realizado con la cuenta que me habían dejado el primer día, aunque en el commit marca mi nombre, quizás por el visual studio pero lo desconozco.

He probado con el tortoise, pasa lo mismo y en ambas herramientas en las configuraciones sale mi cuenta de la empresa, además de que por consola con el comando `git config --global user.email` también sale mi cuenta.

También he borrado el proyecto entero incluido la carpeta .git y lo he vuelto a descargar y me sigue dando el mismo problema. En visual studio, en el history no sale nada de la otra cuenta, salgo solo yo tanto de author como del otro parámetro que no recuerdo ahora mismo y con mi email. Por supuesto he comprobado que fuese el mismo correo, pero como dije en el proyecto anterior me funcionaba sin problemas con mi cuenta.Socorro! xD

Comment: ¿Con qué protocolo haces el push? ¿https o ssh? Si es el segundo quizás estés usando aún la clave pública de la primera cuenta.

Comment: use ssh para clonar en el primer proyecto porque daba problemas el http, pero mostraba mi cuenta en la clave, también la borré por si daba algún problema pero este si que lo estaba clonando por https. Pero en el  push no he definido ningún protocolo.

Comment: Con `git remote -v` puedes ver la URL a la que harás el push. Verás ahi el protocolo. También la URL muestra quién es el propietario del repositorio en Github. Una cosa es el usuario que ves con `user.email` (que es para identificar al autor de los commits), y otra el que hace los push (que es el propietario de la clave privada registrada en Github asociada al repositorio). También puede ser que estés liando el `author` y el `committer`.